# MySQL select max value from derived values grouped by field

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table

```
==============================
| playerId | score1 | score2 |
|============================|
|        1 |      1 |      2 |
|        1 |      5 |      1 |
|        2 |      6 |      6 |
|        2 |      1 |      3 |
==============================
```

I want to sum fields score1 and score2 and find out which player has higher score, so this is where I'm at

```
SELECT MAX(sum(score1) + sum(score2)) FROM player_scores GROUP BY playerId
```

But I get

> 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Try removing the `SUM` functions

Comment: @PatrickQ but then I wont get the summary score :?

Comment: Just for testing purpose...if you remove the max...the query works or still gives you error?

Comment: You want the highest combined score for each player, right? So 1+2 vs 5+1 for playerId = 1. That player's highest score is 6. 6+6 vs 1+3 for playerId = 2. That player's highest score is 12. The results are 6 and 12. If you want something different, you're going to have to rephrase your question and give example results.

Comment: @RobertRozas without `MAX` i get 2 rows with the summed scores of the two players, from which I want to get the higher one and the player id

Comment: @PatrickQ I guess I should have explained it clearly. I want for player 1 1+2+5+1 vs player 2 6+6+1+3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and works.

```
SELECT playerId, SUM( score1 + score2 )
FROM `test`
GROUP BY playerId
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: OH I can't believe I haven't thought of `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`. It is always the simplest things that work best and you miss them.... Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this with a sub select inner select i get the sum and in outer select i have calculated the max of both scores

```
SELECT t.*,MAX(t.score1) + MAX(t.score2) `total` FROM
(
SELECT playerId,sum(score1)score1 ,sum(score2) score2
FROM player_scores 
GROUP BY playerId
) t
GROUP BY t.playerId
```

### [**See fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e63d/4)

Comment: This is the result I need but do I really have to use subqueries, I've heard bad things about those :/

Comment: @php_nub_qq this a co-related subquery and will run once for the inner select to get the desired result set. it is not famous as subquery  has to run for each row

Comment: I see, but it just seems so complicated for such a simple task, as @aleksander's answer proves, there really is a simpler way. Still +rep and thank you too :)